# Relay coil fast demagnetisation

Tags: diodes, relay, driver, zener, coil

In the past few days, I've encountered an application note on the Maxim Integrated website about rapid demagnetisation of an inductive load:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/6/6307.html

There was the technique of using a Zener diode in series with the classic freewheeling diode, and I am interested in knowing how to calculate the Zener voltage and power rating e.g. for a 24 VDC/400 mW relay coil.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The higher voltage you allow the coil to spike at, the faster the current will turn off.

Something, usually a transistor, is driving the inductive load. You have to keep the maximum spike voltage below what will kill the transistor. Different transistors have different breakdown voltages, consult the data sheet for the one you're using.

The Zener has to conduct the same current that the coil does when energised, at a power given by the product of its voltage and the current. It has to absorb the same amount of energy as heat that the coil has stored when on. You rarely find single pulse energy ratings for zener diodes, but generally if they will handle the power and current from a small coil, they'll handle the energy. If it's a big coil, and a small zener (for certain values of small and big) you might have problems.

Comment: So changing to a 150V transistor, e.g. 2N5550, would allow a faster turnoff by dissipating the energy using, say, a 100V or higher voltage zener?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD That's the general idea, yes. If you have good control over the current, and you're a cheapskate, then you could use a resistor instead of a zener, sized so that the current gives you the voltage drop. Initially of course, the voltage will drop as the current falls, but it will still be better than not having an nitial high voltage.

Comment: What is to be done about the higher voltage ringing that happens when the zener no longer passes current? When the voltage expressed by the relay inductance  falls beneath the rated voltage of the zener? (100V in my example above)

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD when the current has fallen to that point, there's no longer any energy stored in the relay's inductance, so what ringing are you talking about? Energy stored in the leads, or in stray capacities? Any further action is going to be all low energy stuff that might be interesting to explain on a 'scope picture, but it's not goingto damage anything that survived the relay turn-off.

Comment: Because of simulating this a bit, I believe that there still may be remaining energy in the inductor.  The diode+zener pair can only extract energy until the voltage falls below the point that current can flow through them. At that point (commonly still around 24V), if no other path exists (and my mental model is correct), the diode capacitances can form a tank circuit with the relay inductor and ring, possibly emitting EMI. This is shown [in my worked-up LTSpice simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecZiO.png). Is there something that I am not taking into account?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD sounds about right, I was only thinking about damage. EMI is a whole different ball game.

Answer (score 3):

Just about any zener will handle the 17mA (decreasing rapidly to zero) current from the coil. An ordinary 400mW type would be fine. If you're insistent on using the smallest SMT type you might want to investigate transient thermal resistance etc.

The voltage should be as high as possible given the capabilities of the driver transistor. Since the load is inductive, you should look at safe operating area as well as simply looking at breakdown voltage, especially for small geometry BJTs. If in doubt, a larger transistor is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The Zener voltage needs to be selected such that the Vdc+Vzener+Vf is less than the breakdown voltage of your high-side switch.

Instantaneous power of the zener needs to be greater than Vzener*Ion; and continuous power of the zener needs to be high enough to deal with the switching duty cycle of the relay.

Choose safety factors for your voltages and powers that suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The Zener voltage is chosen to keep the voltage on the drain of the MOSFET below its breakdown voltage.

Example:
VDC = 330 Volt
Vbreakdown = 650 Volt
Vflyback = 200 Volt (Voltage developed by the coil)

Vmargin = Vbreakdown - Vflyback - VDC

Vmargin = 650 - 330 - 200 = 120 Volt

Vzener must be smaller than Vmargin.

In this particular case I would pick a 100 Volt Zener diode.

Note:
In my formula I omitted the leakage inductance of the coil in order to keep my answer simple.

Answer (score 0):

If the zener has the capability of more watts than the relay coil normally consumes, there will be no way to damage the zener, because there's no way to put more energy into the zener than first goes into the coil.