# Is this ringing a problem after "Relay coil fast demagnetization". If so, how to stop

Tags: diodes, relay, driver, zener, coil

In the question [Relay coil fast demagnetisation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/591441/relay-coil-fast-demagnetisation), a diode and a zener were used in series to quickly remove the energy from an inductor. The question posed an example of a 24VDC 400mW relay, and I simulated it in LTSpice.

When the zener is finished taking its energy because it stopped conducting, there is a ringing that occurs, and I want to know if it's a problem, and what to do about it if so.

Here's my circuit:

[image]

And here's the ringing across the inductor, from 25V to -25V, and about 100uA peak-to-peak:

[image]

---

EDIT:

I followed the advice of Tony, but increased the resistor until I liked the response, from 1K to 33K, and you can see the before and after below:

[image]

The parameters for the relay came from page 4 of a [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Electric%20Works%20PDFs/NC_Relays.pdf) for [Panasonic # NC4D-P-DC24V](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electric-works/NC4D-P-DC24V/280726).  I mixed two different relays together (and Jonk caught it!)

[image]

Here is the final circuit:

[image]

Comment: Before other thoughts, I do a "sanity check" of what I'm seeing in front of me. Here, I get \$\frac{\left(24\:\text{V}\right)^2}{400\:\text{mW}}=1440 \:\Omega\$. That comports with your figure. But small DC relays (my vague memory) tend to anticipate about \$3\:\text{ms}\$ timing. So this means \$L=1440 \:\Omega\cdot 3\:\text{ms}\approx 4.3\:\text{H}\$. I'd check the datasheet. But if the time they specify matches my memory, then that's the value I'd use for inductance. Did you have a different way of arriving at your figure?

Comment: The magnet force time constant controls acceleration of the switch but the contact travel velocity will be constant after several L/DCR time constants and then the contact will mate.

Comment: @jonk - The relay in the referenced question did not specify one, so I had to find one, and I mixed the specs together just a bit, stretching reality because I wanted extra inductance for the problem. Great catch, Jonk!

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD It's just basic sanity checking, like dimensional analysis to make sure units are correctly applied. Nothing special. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

120 uApp at approx. 80kHz resonance is not much current or magnetic power since it is AC compared with 24V/1k4= 17.1 mA DC.

But if you are concerned about EMI or have an academic interest, you can dampen the self resonant frequency with the switch, diode and winding  capacitance.

I can suggest a low Q damping solution that won't affect the fast Turn off time with the reverse Zener + reverse diode.

**Add 1k across the 24V Zener.**